# module pygame has no member QUIT?

Tags: python, pygame

simple code but still not able to figure out where things are going wrong,
it says module pygame has no member QUIT,quit

```
import pygame
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run=False
    
    pygame.quit()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already imported pygame you can just do "QUIT" instead of "pygame.QUIT"

Comment: yup it gives the same one,but now no quit member sort of